# From a boolean table keep lists with existing values

Tags: r

Having a Boolean frame like this:

```
dftest <- data.frame(id = c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"), stock1= c(1,0,0,1,0), stock2 = c(1,1,0,1,0), stock3 = c(0,1,0,0,0))



id stock1 stock2 stock3
A1      1      1      0
A2      0      1      1
A3      0      0      0
A4      1      1      0
A5      0      0      0
```

How is it possible to extract lists like this:

```
stock1 = c("A1,","A4")
stock2 = c("A1","A2","A4")
stock3 = c("A2")
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution with `lapply` and simple subsetting:

```
lapply(names(dftest)[-1], function(x) dftest[dftest[x] == 1, 'id'])

#[[1]]
#[1] A1 A4
#5 Levels: A1 A2 A3 ... A5

#[[2]]
#[1] A1 A2 A4
#5 Levels: A1 A2 A3 ... A5

#[[3]]
#[1] A2
#5 Levels: A1 A2 A3 ... A5
```

Your id column is currently of type factor. If you don't want to see the levels in the output, just convert it to character, i.e. `dftest$id <- as.character(dftest$id)`

Comment: or `lapply(dftest[-1], FUN=function(x) dftest$id[as.logical(x)])`

Answer (score 1):

```
    stocks <- list(NULL)

    for (i in 2: ncol(dftest)) {
      stocks[[i-1]] <- dftest$id[dftest[,i]==1]
    }

    names(stocks) <- colnames(dftest)[2: ncol(dftest)]
```

The results are as follows.

```
>stocks
$stock1
[1] A1 A4
Levels: A1 A2 A3 A4 A5

$stock2
[1] A1 A2 A4
Levels: A1 A2 A3 A4 A5

$stock3
[1] A2
Levels: A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
```

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
data.table::melt(dftest, id.vars = "id")[as.logical(value), list(list(id)), by = variable][[2]]

[[1]]
[1] A1 A4
Levels: A1 A2 A3 A4 A5

[[2]]
[1] A1 A2 A4
Levels: A1 A2 A3 A4 A5

[[3]]
[1] A2
Levels: A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be using `mapply`, convert 1/0 data to logical and subset the corresponding `id`s from each column to get list of `id`s.

```
mapply(`[`, dftest["id"], data.frame(dftest[-1] == 1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)

#[[1]]
#[1] "A1" "A4"

#[[2]]
#[1] "A1" "A2" "A4"

#[[3]]
#[1] "A2"
```

**data**

```
dftest <- data.frame(id = c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"),
                     stock1= c(1,0,0,1,0), 
                     stock2 = c(1,1,0,1,0), 
                     stock3 = c(0,1,0,0,0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(dftest, key, val, -id) %>% 
    filter(val == 1) %>%
    group_split(key) %>%
     map(pluck, 'id')
#[[1]]
#[1] A1 A4
#Levels: A1 A2 A3 A4 A5

#[[2]]
#[1] A1 A2 A4
#Levels: A1 A2 A3 A4 A5

#[[3]]
#[1] A2
#Levels: A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
```

---

Or using `map`

```
map(dftest[-1], ~ as.character(dftest$id)[!! .x])
#$stock1
#[1] "A1" "A4"

#$stock2
#[1] "A1" "A2" "A4"

#$stock3
#[1] "A2"
```

Or with `map` and `discard`

```
map(dftest[-1], ~ discard(dftest$id, !.x))
```

---

Or an option with `base R` using `split`

```
with(subset(cbind(dftest['id'], stack(dftest, -id)), 
          values == 1), split(as.character(id), ind))
#$stock1
#[1] "A1" "A4"

#$stock2
#[1] "A1" "A2" "A4"

#$stock3
#[1] "A2"
```

Or using `split` by replicating the 'id' column and the `names`

```
split(dftest[col(dftest[-1])][c(!!dftest[-1])], 
         names(dftest)[-1][col(dftest[-1])][c(!!dftest[-1])])
```